# CPU and Memory metrics in Prometheus format for a Gunicorn application

Tags: python, kubernetes, prometheus, gunicorn, statsd

I am currently working on a CI/CD deployment of an application written in Python which runs on Gunicorn in K8's. I am using HELM chart to do the deployments. Application has already StatsD implementation to monitor for metrics but stasd has a limitation for CPU and Memory metrics. I have been looking into Prometheus client library implementation but their python library has [limitations](https://github.com/prometheus/client_python#multiprocess-mode-eg-gunicorn) for Gunicorn. Need help in enabling metrics for the application. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: did you figure this out? i'm facing the same issue